# CHROME - How to see when a request is launched?

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector

I'm trying to find information about WHEN a HTTP request has been "launched" to the server. In my chrome web inspector, network tab, I have some info about the internal timing of the http session (time before first byte, queuing, response..), but nothing about when those session starts/ends.

Is there a way to get this info?

Comment: what do you mean "when" as in, you want the time and date the request was made?

Comment: yes! date and time

Comment: There's a plugin for Firefox called TamperData that is very useful for examining and even changing live requests. If FireFox is an option, I would HIGHLY recommend that. It includes date and time. There is also a tool called RequestMaker for Chrome. I haven't tried it, but people who like it compare it to TamperData. Hope that helps.